# Laravel: Return 2 collections in axios-response

Tags: laravel

For my axios response I want to return 2 Collections (in my laravel controller). so far I always had just one return value, like so:

```
[..]
return $mycollection1;
```

How can I return 2 seperate collections? Since the following is not the right way I figured :)

```
[..]
return $mycollection1;
return $mycollection2;
```

Do I have to merge these 2 collections, or creating an array or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your controller

```
return [
  'mycollection1' => $mycollection1,
  'mycollection2' => $mycollection1
];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this.

```
return $mycollection1->merge(mycollection2);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can send both collection as array. return means no more code will execute after that return line. so multiple return won't work. you have to do it like

```
return response()->json([$collection1, $collection2]);
```

and in response you can access both as `response[0]` and `response[1]`

don't use `merge()` because if some objects happen to have the same id, one will overwrite the other. so return as array.